# Fixed Nav, website content then moves up - How to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I am working on a page that has a top banner followed by a top navigation bar. I am making it so that when you scroll down past the navigation bar - the navigation bar becomes fixed. This works however when the nav becomes fixed, the rest of the website content pushes up as the navigation bar is no longer a block element.

Is there a way to make the navigation bar fixed while retaining the position or content of the page in the same location?

Comment: Seeing that you are new...Please add some relevant code or add to JSfiddle

Comment: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit

Comment: Very superficial question, please add some resource with an example of it(e.g. in jsfiddle.net)

Comment: you could make the navigation bar position absolute and give the content of the page a margin-top as the same height as the navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the margin-top of the div with the rest of the website equal to the height of the navigation bar + margin-top of the navigation bar (since there is a banner)

Answer (score 0):

What sort of script are you using to switch the positioning of your navigation? I've used jQuery Waypoints (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/) with success. Maybe you could use that, or check out how they address your issue. It seems like they add a wrapper around the "sticky element", which prevents the content from shifting.